# I am trying to output a string from array in 8086 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, x86-16

```
BITS 16
ORG 0x0100

SECTION .text
MAIN:

      mov DI,array
      call GetString
      call Putln
      call PutString
      call Putln
      mov SI,array
      ;jmp Next

;Next:
      mov AX,4C00H
      ;mov AL,00H
      int 21H

%INCLUDE 'STDIO.ASM'

SECTION .data
mesg db  'I','h','a','t','e','a','s','s','e','m','b','l','y' ;


SECTION .bss
array resb 256  ;reserve 256 bytes of space



Putch:                   ;outputs character in DL
     push DI
     mov AH,02H
     int 21H
     pop DI

     ret

Getch:                   ;inputs a character into AL
     push DI
    ; mov BH,AH
     mov AH,08H
     int 21H
    ; mov AH,BH
     mov DL,AL
     pop DI
     ret

Putln:                 ;prints out a new line
    mov AH,02H
    mov DL,CR
    int 21H
    mov DL,LF
    int 21H
    ret

GetString:
        call Getch
        cmp DL,0DH
        je End
        call Putch
        stosb
        jmp GetString

End:
  mov AL,00H
  stosb
  ret


PutString:
       cld
       lodsb
       cmp AL,00H
       jz End1
       mov DL,AL
       call Putch
       jmp PutString

End1:
    ret

SECTION .data
;mesg db  'I',' ','h','a','t','e',' ','a','s','s','e','m','b','l','y' ;
CR  equ  0AH
LF  equ  0AH
```

I am trying to output a string from array in 8086 assembly, but when I run it, even though I can input characters, when I press Enter it gives me symblols.

Comment: Try moving your `mov si, array` before the `call PutString`... (and `CR equ 0Dh`, not 0Ah)

Comment: I did it but now it doesnt even print the message. Any other suggestions?

Comment: No. :) That "should" work! Your `mesg` is not zero-terminated, which `PutString` expects... but you're not attempting to print that(?). Your `GetString` "should" put a zero-terminated string where `di` points (`array`), and your `PutString` "should" print a zero-terminated string from where `si` points (`array` again, no?). Got a debugger?

Comment: So how can i zero terminate it? I am attempting to print the string yes. :)

Comment: Just add a 0 at the end of it. `mesg db "I love assembly", 0` You don't need to list the letters separately - `db` will accept a "list of bytes". I'm not conveniently able to test your code, but it "looks okay" to me.

Answer (score 2):

I think your data segment register might not be set up correctly.
As you're operating in real mode, it is good to start your program with

```
mov ax,.data    ; The way this is done can vary between assemblers
mov ds,ax
```

Also, as long as I remember, DOS calls operate not with zero-terminated strings, but ones with '$' at the end, so the cause might be that you did not declare `mesg` as follows:

```
mesg db 'I love assembly!$'
```

(Actually, you seem not to have the string terminted by any means)